# Type traits and template overload resolution

Tags: c++, templates, type-traits

I'm writing a type trait to check that a given type is a specific container and I came across the following situation:

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <cstddef>

template<typename T>
struct is_char_array_t final: std::false_type {};
template<std::size_t N>
struct is_char_array_t<std::array<char, N>> final: std::true_type {};

int main(){
    if constexpr (is_char_array_t<42>) {
        return 2;
    } 
}
```

This code doesn't compile, the error it gives is:

```
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:10:37: error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for 'template<class T> struct is_char_array_t'
   10 |     if constexpr (is_char_array_t<42>) {
      |                                     ^
<source>:10:37: note:   expected a type, got '42'
<source>:10:38: error: expected unqualified-id before ')' token
   10 |     if constexpr (is_char_array_t<42>) {
      |                                      ^
ASM generation compiler returned: 1
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:10:37: error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for 'template<class T> struct is_char_array_t'
   10 |     if constexpr (is_char_array_t<42>) {
      |                                     ^
<source>:10:37: note:   expected a type, got '42'
<source>:10:38: error: expected unqualified-id before ')' token
   10 |     if constexpr (is_char_array_t<42>) {
      |                                      ^
Execution build compiler returned: 1
```

The behavior is what I want, since it doesn't let anything that isn't a `std::array<char, N>`  match the trait, but I'm left wondering why it works.

I would think that the template overload for `std::size_t` is a better match for the value `42` than the template that requires a type. So why doesn't the second, more specialized template match the given value?

Here's a godbolt with the example: https://godbolt.org/z/KdKvrPsx3

Comment: i don't understand what you mean "why it works". A trait is usually used to yield true of false, but your code has an error

Comment: What I meant with "why it works" is why the value passed to the template parameter  isn't resolved to the template specialization that accepts a `size_t`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the template:

```
template<typename T>
struct is_char_array_t final: std::false_type {};    // (I)
```

And this is a specialization:

```
template<std::size_t N>
struct is_char_array_t<std::array<char, N>> final: std::true_type {};
```

The specialization is not a new template. It does not change the fact that `is_char_array` has one type argument. It merely specializes the primary template (`I`) for the case that `T` matches `std::array<char,N>`. The specialization starts with `template <std::size_t N>` because `N` is a "free parameter", you do not care what `N` is for the specialization as long as the type `T` is a `std::array<char,N>` for some `N`. In other words, it is a partial specialization. A full specialization would start with `template <>` and have no such "free parameter". You can identify the specialization by the `is_char_array_t<std::array<char, N>>` where the primary template only mentions the name of the template.

Your code does not really "work". The trait is used to yield either true or false, depending on the type that is used to instantiate it. Using a value is an error.

Answer (score 0):

The primary template (the first one in your code) declares `is_char_array_t` as such:

```
template<typename T>
struct is_char_array_t;
```

That means `is_char_array_t` is a class template expecting exactly one template argument which should be a type template argument.

You are trying to give it `42` as template argument, which is a value, not a type. Therefore `is_char_array_t<42>` is wrong, no matter how `is_char_array_t` is implemented or partially specialized. Class templates also can't be overloaded, so this can never change.

Also, it is clearly *not* working. If it was working, then there wouldn't be any error message. `if constexpr`'s condition would simply evaluate to `false` and the branch wouldn't be taken, so that the resulting program end with `0` status code instead.